# Android: How to remove SLF4J debug logging with ProGuard

Tags: android, logging, proguard, slf4j

I use SLF4J in my Android application for logging purposes. In the release build I don't want all the debug logs to appear, so I tried to remove them with ProGuard. But the log statements are still printed to the logcat console and I can't figure out on my own what i am doing wrong. It's the first time that I use ProGuard, so any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

**MainActivity.java**

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MainActivity {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName());

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        log.debug("Starting application.");
    }
}
```

**project-proguard.txt**

```
-assumenosideeffects class org.slf4j.Logger {
    public *** trace(...);
    public *** debug(...);
}
```

**project-proguard.txt (extended as the first version did not work)**

```
-assumenosideeffects class org.slf4j.Logger {
    public *** trace(...);
    public *** debug(...);
}
-assumenosideeffects interface org.slf4j.Logger {
    public *** trace(...);
    public *** debug(...);
}
-assumenosideeffects class * implements org.slf4j.Logger {
    public *** trace(...);
    public *** debug(...);
}
-assumenosideeffects class * implements org.slf4j.Logger {
    public void trace(java.lang.String);
    public void trace(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object);
    public void trace(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
    public void trace(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[]);
    public void trace(java.lang.String, java.lang.Throwable);
    public void trace(org.slf4j.Marker, java.lang.String);
    public void trace(org.slf4j.Marker, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object);
    public void trace(org.slf4j.Marker, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
    public void trace(org.slf4j.Marker, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[]);
    public void trace(org.slf4j.Marker, java.lang.String, java.lang.Throwable);
    public void debug(java.lang.String);
    public void debug(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object);
    public void debug(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
    public void debug(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[]);
    public void debug(java.lang.String, java.lang.Throwable);
    public void debug(org.slf4j.Marker, java.lang.String);
    public void debug(org.slf4j.Marker, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object);
    public void debug(org.slf4j.Marker, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object);
    public void debug(org.slf4j.Marker, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[]);
    public void debug(org.slf4j.Marker, java.lang.String, java.lang.Throwable);
}
```

**logcat - debug build**

```
01-08 11:27:02.105  31142-31142/com.example.android D/MainActivity﹕ Starting application.
```

**logcat - release build (should not be there!)**

```
01-08 11:30:08.615  26483-26483/? D/MainActivity﹕ Starting application.
```

Comment: The only thing in your long configuration that worked for me was the section that references the interface.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, and I solved it using two steps.

**First and most important step**

In your gradle file, you have to specify the usage of the proguard-android-optimize.txt as default file.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        // With the file below, it does not work!
        //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Actually, in the default `proguard-android.txt` file, optimization is disabled with the two flags:

```
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
```

The `proguard-android-optimize.txt` file does not add those lines, so now `assumenosideeffects` can work.

**Second step**

In your own `proguard-rules.pro` file, you can add:

```
-assumenosideeffects class * implements org.slf4j.Logger {
    public *** trace(...);
    public *** debug(...);
    public *** info(...);
    public *** warn(...);
    public *** error(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

do you specify field/removal/writeonly optimiazation within -optimizations ?
something like below:

`-optimizations field/removal/writeonly`

Answer (score 1):

Spent a lot of time on this problem, for me MLProgrammer-CiM answer works. I would recommend this.

Some modifications as `releaseCompile`, `debugCompile` are dericated.

```
publicReleaseImplementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25'
debugImplementation  'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.25'
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't proguard, just use the no-op version of SLF4J for release versions.

```
releaseCompile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12'
debugCompile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.12'
```

Comment: The problem with a no-op version is that logs and their string content are still in the final binary. Nothing is printed, but for security reason, sometimes it is preferable to completely remove the log lines: someone can try to extract all strings from the final binary for instance.
Anyway, it is true that it answers the question, since it was only about not printing logs.

Comment: If people are decompiling the apk I would be more worried about what are not the logs :P

Comment: Replacing with nop is not secure at all.. the reason to remove logs is that logs give a lot of insight on the behaviour off the app/lib as well as on what the many obfuscated variables really are. It's crucial to actually remove the lines completely.